# How to perform double tap to zoom on android device with adb shell

Tags: adb, shell

I want to perform a double tap on the screen or mouse with `adb shell`. Is this possible? I'm not interested in waking or turning off the screen, but to increase the zoom on a picture.

Comment: @Firelord I want to double tap to zoom in / zoom out in pictures or websites, not related to waking the device.

Comment: Have you tried the keyevent 168? It seems to work here. 169 for zoom out.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Firelord for pointing out the solution. These are several keyevents that work on a Samsung Galaxy S7. You cand send either the code or the name of the event:

Turn on/off the screen (clicking the power button):

`adb shell input keyevent 26
 adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_POWER`

Zoom in a little bit:

`adb shell input keyevent 168
 adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ZOOM_IN`

Zoom out a little bit:

`adb shell input keyevent 169
 adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ZOOM_OUT`

See all the official KeyEvents on Google Developer's page:
[Android KeyEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

Another option, much more powerful and sophisticated, is to use [minitouch](https://github.com/openstf/minitouch), which is a minimal multitouch event producer for Android.